# Node.js sample code not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to run some simple codes of node.js, this hello world works without a problem:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("Este node.js criou um servidor\n");
});


server.listen(8000);
```

But when I try to run this one that should be simple enough, the browser (tried IE and chrome) stays loading for a long time and then gives a timeout. What could be the problem?

```
var http = require("http"),
fs = require("fs");
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   request.on('end', function () {
      if (request.url == '/') {
         fs.readFile('test.txt', 'utf-8', function (error, data) {
            response.writeHead(200, {
               'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
            });
            data = parseInt(data) + 1;
            fs.writeFile('test.txt', data);
            response.end('This page was refreshed ' + data + ' times!');
         });
      } else {
         response.writeHead(404);
         response.end();
      }
   });
}).listen(8000);
```

By the way, I've created the test.txt file in the same folder as the code and it have only the number 1 inside it.

Comment: I don't think you need the `request.on('end', function () { ...})` callback. Already when the `function (request, response) { ... }` is called you know that a request has been generated.

Comment: IIRC it should be `fs.readFile('test.txt', {encoding: 'utf-8'}, fn);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The end request never launch, because the request is finished when the server is called. Remove that line and ready like this:

```
var http = require("http"),
  fs = require("fs");
  http.createServer(function (request, response) {
     // request.on('end', function () {
        if (request.url == '/') {
           fs.readFile('test.txt', 'utf-8', function (error, data) {
              response.writeHead(200, {
                 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
              });
              data = parseInt(data) + 1;
              fs.writeFile('test.txt', data);
              response.end('This page was refreshed ' + data + ' times!');
           });
        } else {
           response.writeHead(404);
           response.end();
        }
     // });
  }).listen(8000);
```

Comment: "*because the request is finished when the server is called*" Not quite. It's because the `request` isn't streaming its body (even if the body is empty). A `'readable'` or `'data'` binding or a forced `.resume()` is needed to start it. When the `createServer` or `'request'` callback is called, only the headers have been read through.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, what is weird is that I followed exactly what was writen in tutsplus, so this tutorial is wrong http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/node-js-for-beginners/

Comment: It is not wrong, it just wasn't written for [streams2](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/12/20/streams2/).

Answer (score 2):

The request object from a HTTP handler is an instance of readable stream, which will not emit the `end` event when in non-flowing mode. If an `end` event is expected, then the stream must be resumed..

If you aren't going to collect the body of the request, then you don't need to listen for the `end` event at all. You can just write the response:

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (request.url == '/') {
    fs.readFile('test.txt', 'utf-8', function (error, data) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      data = parseInt(data) + 1;
      fs.writeFile('test.txt', data);
      res.end('This page was refreshed ' + data + ' times!');
    });
  } else {
    res.writeHead(404);
    res.end();
  }
}).listen();
```

Otherwise, the stream can converted to flowing mode by either of these:

```
req.resume();
req.on('data', function(chunk) {});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that it seems to be structured is quite different from what I have seen otherwise. You shouldn't need the request.on structure. Generally, you could using something like this:

```
var http = require("http");

var Start = function(){

    var onRequest = function(request, response){

        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "text/plain" });
        response.write("HEllo World");
        response.end();
    }

    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
}

exports.Start = Start;
```

The reason for the exports is so that you can start it form another file (which is good if you are going for the suggested modular design. As to loading files - your way of loading may work, but the problem is that it will only server text file - trying to use an html file will fail miserably, and you probably want to be serving html files as well, along with .js and .css files as well (and anything else, for example pictures). Therefore, please refer to my answer, which is the very long one with plenty of code, in the folllowing link: [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19827764/2697921).